# Active Navigation Anchor Links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've done a search both on here and via Google, I've tried all the codes that they have given me, and no success on any of them. I've got no idea at all why they don't work.
Basically when you scroll the page and reach the anchor link "about" I want "about" to be highlighted until you get to "events", etc.

```
<div id="menu-wrapper">
    <div id="menu">
            <ul>
            <li class="logo"><a href="#home"><img src="/images/ccky_logo.png" height="60"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#events">Events</a></li>
            <li><a href="#team">Team</a></li>
            <li><a href="#location">Location</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- end #menu -->
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: you can look at the [twitter bootstrap implementation](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use bootstrap's Scrollspy to achieve this effect: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#scrollspy

After you implemented the JavaScript plugin simply call it with `$('#menu').scrollspy()`.

In your HTML, just add the data parameters bootstrap instructs you to use.

Comment: I know this sounds really bad, but I haven't the foggiest where to start. Could your give me a few pointers?

Comment: You need to include the JS and CSS files from Bootstrap into your website, and basically follow what it says on the Bootstrap website. You need to respect the layout they show there, and the method of implementation. I understand that is seems intimidating if you're not used to it, but fumbling around is the best way to learn. If you have any specific question, I'm happy to answer them.